# Android - ArrayList containing Bluetooth devices remains empty

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to discover all available bluetooth devices and pass to another activity.
However even when looking at the Android Docs, I am unable to figure out why I cannot discover any devices and my ArrayList remains empty.

OnClick execute this:

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

My broadcast listener also works but nothing is every returned and ArrayList remains empty.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        mDeviceList.add(device);
        showToast("Found device " + device.getName());
    }

    if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
        final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
        if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
            showToast("Enabled");
            showEnabled();
        }
    }
    if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
        mDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();
        mProgressDlg.show();
    }
    if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
        mProgressDlg.dismiss();

        Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
        if (mDeviceList.isEmpty()){
            Log.d("onReceive: ", "EMPTY");
        }
        newIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", mDeviceList);

        startActivity(newIntent);
    }

}
```

};

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/J2quared/34ef0f2631d8c131f00208c2f92ac675)

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.

The fix was to turn location on with app permissions.

Apparently this is required for Android Marshmallow

Comment: Location shouldn't be a problem with Bluetooth. Are you sure  that's the solution?

Comment: I changed startDiscovery to BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().startDiscovery(); that didn't work so then I made sure location services was on in Settings > App > Location

Comment: Right, so you enabled Bluetooth discovery, not "enabled location" implying GPS .

Comment: By toggling location (GPS) are you not enabling it in settings > App > app name > Permission

Comment: I'm just not sure how GPS setting affects Bluetooth problems, that's all

Comment: The same rule apply for scanning WiFi networks. Because you can use WiFi and Bluetooth to track the user's position without their knowledge, the system requires you to allow and enable location before scanning anything